# Alarm not going off when it should

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm working on `AlarmManager`; I've created an alarmManager (based on a tutorial) which can be set to go off at a specific time, but the problem here is that as soon as I set time and click the ok button in the `TimePickerDialog` the alarm goes off no matter when it should. However, the toast is shown when it's supposed to.

What am I missing?

Here is my code:

AndroidTimeActivity.java

```
public class AndroidTimeActivity extends Activity {

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
TimePicker myTimePicker;
Button buttonstartSetDialog;
TextView textAlarmPrompt;

TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

final static int RQS_1 = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

textAlarmPrompt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);

buttonstartSetDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
textAlarmPrompt.setText("");
openTimePickerDialog(false);

        }
    });

}


private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
    AndroidTimeActivity.this,
    onTimeSetListener,
    calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
    calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
    is24r);
    timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");

    timePickerDialog.show();

}

OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener
    = new OnTimeSetListener(){

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){

    calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        setAlarm(calSet);
    }
};

private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon1);
                    mBuilder.setContentTitle("My notification");
                    mBuilder.setContentText("Hello World!");
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.applenett.myapplication/raw/ringtone1"));




    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);




    notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());


}

}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".AndroidTimeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alarm_receiver"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:process=":remote">
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());` right then so  that notification (and the sound accompanying it) will fire then b/c you've asked it to. You should move the whole notification builder (and notify) section to the alarm receiver class so it will get triggered along with the toast at that time.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked. I had to change NotificationManager line to " NotificationManager notificationManager =  (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);" to get rid of the "cannot resolve method" error.